# gaussian mixture model is inconsistent in its results using sklearn library

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn

so I am trying to segment a hand from an image using the Gaussian mixture model, so read [this paper (Hand Gesture Based Recognition And Voice Conversion System For Physically Disabled People)](https://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jece/papers/Conf.MAM-2019/Volume-1/6.%2037-41.pdf) which states that skin color follows gaussian distribution in YCbCr color space, so I wrote the following line :

```
gmm_model = GMM.GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type='full', warm_start=True, init_params='k-means++').fit(img2)
```

from sklearn library, but my problem is that every time I run the program the results are different completely.

### here is the original image:

[image]

### here is the segmented image for the 1st run:

[image]

### here is the segmented image for the 2nd run:

[image]

and so on, why is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn's implementation of Gaussian mixtures is non-deterministic. So if you call `.fit(...)` twice, you *expect* to get two different results.

Let me expand on this. In Sklearn, a Gaussian mixture model is trained by a process called expecation-maximisation. Very roughly (and at the risk of oversimplifying), expectation-maximisation is an iterative algorithm, where you start with an initial guess for the cluster centres/sizes, and then you iteratively improve your guess. Given a choice of initial guess, the process of iterative improvement is perfectly deterministic. However, the way that sklearn generates the initial guess in the first place is non-deterministic.

Looking at your code, it appears that your initial guess is generated by the `k-means++` method. Now look at section 2.1.1.4 in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html), where it is stated that the `k-means++` method for generating the initial guess has an element of randomness.

To get rid of the randomness, I suggest you set `random_state` equal to some fixed number. See [these docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture).